# Form validation before submit data to SharePoint list (PowerApps)

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a form created in PowerApps. Few fields are required for user to fill in. I need to have a form validation before user can click Submit button.

Upon submit button:
- All required are fill in
- All data saved to SharePoint list
- Navigate to 'Thank you' page

I have this link in 'OnSelect' for Submit button
If((IsEmpty(Data1, Data2), SubmitForm(Form), Navigate(ThankYouPage, Fade)), false)

But it just navigate to Thank you page even required fields are empty.

Looking forward to your responses. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just a minor change onselect.

```
If(@not((IsEmpty(Data1, Data2)), SubmitForm(Form), Navigate(ThankYouPage, Fade)), false)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best do not use Navigate on **OnSubmit** Button, it is better to use it on the **OnSuccess** Property of the form control.

a. Formula on the **OnSelect** for **OnSubmit** Button

If((IsEmpty(Data1, Data2), SubmitForm(Form))

b. Formula on the **OnSuccess** property of the form control

Navigate(ThankYouPage, Fade))

For more info reach the following website:

http://ashishcoder.com/courses/power-apps/topic-54/submitform-resetform-functions.html